# giving an id to semaphore

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

Hi I want to maintain a list of semaphores created and their allowed count (no of thread instances allowed to access that semaphore) value. I tried with a map in stl like

```
map<sem_t, int> sem_map;
```

so that the key(sem_t) has the count as value in the map.

but c++ is not allowing me to use sem_t as a key as it is (sem_t) a union type. So, how can i maintain a semaphore list? My goal is whenever i want to lock or unlock the semaphore i first get the id of the semaphore from my maintained list and do some pre-processing with it.

Comment: Could you not store something like map<int, sem_t> sem_map where threadID is your key and you union type is the value? Otherwise you need to declare and deifne a class to hold your semaphore, max num of threads, current num of threads, thread id and optional string identifier

Comment: Hi, I thought so, just wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the sem_t's address as the key:

```
map<sem_t*, int> sem_map;
```

Then, given a sem_t x, you could access the int value in the map using:

```
sem_map.find(&x);
```

Note that this solution works only if you are not copying semaphores around.

EDIT: the reason why you couldn't use sem_t as keys in your map is that std::map requires that the key type has operator< defined(in order to do internal sorting, std::map(s) are tree structures). However, a union does not have a operator< defined, so the compiler won't let you use it. On the other hand, pointers can be compared between them, so the compiler will actually let you use them as keys in your std::map.

Comment: btw can you explain why c++ did not allow sem_t but allowed sem_t* instead?

Comment: understood. When i tried to debug it took me to the < operator overloading method.

Comment: It's not a good idea to copy `sem_t` objects in any case. It may often work, but as the posix spec says, "References to copies of the semaphore produce undefined results".

Comment: I just added that note as a reminder. Copying semaphores is not something i usually do :P.